# SnowPlow Analytics Schemas

Tags: snowplow

Trying to create a schema with arrays for data retrieved from performance insights.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://iglucentral.com/schemas/com.snowplowanalytics.self-desc/schema/jsonschema/1-0-0#",
    "description": "Performance Insights",
    "self": {
        "vendor": "com.acme",
        "name": "performance_insights",
        "format": "jsonschema",
        "version": "1-0-3"
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "SeriesStartTime": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time",
            "description" : "timestamp"
        },
        "SeriesEndtime": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time",
            "description" : "timestamp"
        },
        "Identifier": {
            "description": "DataBase",
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 128
        },
        "MetricList": {
            "type": "array",
            "items":{
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Key": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "description": "Key Metric",
                    "properties": {
                        "Metric": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Load Avg"
                        },
                        "Dimensions": {
                            "properties": {
                                "tokenized_db": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "maxLength": 128
                                },
                                "tokenized_id": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "maxLength": 128
                                },
                                "tokenized_statement": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },                
                "DataPoints": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Timestamp": {
                            "description" : "timestamp",
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "date-time"
                        },
                        "Value": {
                            "description" : "Value",
                            "type": "number"
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        },
        "minItems": 1
    }
    
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
    
}
```

It lints ok then I send data to it:

```
{
      "schema": "iglu:com.acme/performance_insights/jsonschema/1-0-3",
      "data": {
        "SeriesStartTime": "2021-12-09T19:00:00-05:00",
        "SeriesEndtime": "2021-12-09T20:00:00-05:00",
        "Identifier": "db-5LHLHN5OGHFFFFMHRGDM",
        "MetricList": [
            {
                "Key": {
                    "Metric": "db.load.avg"
                },
                "DataPoints": [
                    {
                        "Timestamp": "2021-12-09T19:01:00-05:00",
                        "Value": 0.01818181818181818
                    },
                    {
                        "Timestamp": "2021-12-09T19:25:00-05:00",
                        "Value": 0.01818181818181818
                    }
                ]
            }]
    }
    }
```

I've pushed the schema to my repo I have push a couple others which work but not so complex as to receive array data.

Seems when I intentionally put the type wrong I see errors in my bad collector.
When everything is correct as above I only see

```
schemaKey:"iglu:com.acme/performance_insights/jsonschema/1-0-3"
schemaCriterion:"iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/payload_data/jsonschema/1-0-*"
```

As a failure.message

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think you need to add more details or perhaps tag this differently.  What does this have to do with Snowflake?

Comment: darn so many names i meant to tag snowplow!!  thank you will update

Answer (score 0):

I'm making these assumptions:

- the bad rows that you are citing in your example are of type `tracker_protocol_violations`
- they are of subtype `CriterionMismatch`.

This type of failure happens when the supplied payload is a valid JSON and it is a self-describing one, but it's schema does not match the associated schema criterion. The `failure.message` shows you the schema of the failed event and the schema criterion that needed to be matched.

In your case the schema is `com.acme/performance_insights/jsonschema/1-0-3` but the criterion to match is `com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/payload_data/jsonschema/1-0-*`.

You are seeing this error because the self-describing event needs to be wrapped up in a `com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/payload_data` schema. like this:

```
{
  "schema": "com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/payload_data/jsonschema/1-0-4",
  "data": [
    "...": "...",
    "ue_px": "<base64-encoded-string>",
    "...": "..."
  ]  
}
```

where `<base64-encoded-string>` is the base64-encoded JSON with the `com.acme/performance_insights` schema.

You can read more about this type of failure in the Snowplow documentation [here](https://docs.snowplowanalytics.com/docs/managing-data-quality/failed-events/understanding-failed-events/#tracker-protocol-violation).